# Bash, grep between a line with specified string till a character (not include)

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, grep

Example:

```
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines1
some_lines2
some_lines3
> header bcf and blablabla
some_lines4
some_lines5
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines6
>......
```

Here i want grep the line with '**abc**' and all lines after it before another '**>**', the result should be like:

```
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines1
some_lines2
some_lines3
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines6
> ...
```

Since the number of lines in between is not fixed, i can't apply `grep -A`
I've also tried using sed, but doesnt work well:

```
sed -n '/abc/,/>/p' file
```

Unwanted result:

```
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines1
some_lines2
some_lines3
> header bcf and blablabla
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines6
```

Another sed:

```
sed -n '/abc/,/>/{/abc/b;/>/b;p}' file
```

Unwanted result:

```
some_lines1
some_lines2
some_lines3
some_lines6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/^>/{p=0} /abc/{p=1} p' file
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines1
some_lines2
some_lines3
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines6
```

Comment: @once: This is a simple awk. A flag `p` is set to `1` when we find `abc` in a line and it resets to `0` when we find `^` at a line start. Having `p` in the end just prints or skips a line depending upon it's value being 1 or 0

Comment: Won't this set the flag for any line that contains abc, not just the one beginning with `>`...

Comment: I believe that is what OP wants but better off we get more clarification from OP.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Poz '^> .*abc.*(\n[^>].*)*' file
```

Output:

```
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines1
some_lines2
some_lines3
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines6
```

Comment: but seems my system not supporting -Poz

Comment: `-z` for multiline grepping! Very neat.

Answer (score 1):

In sed

```
sed '/abc/{:1;n;/^>/!b1};d' file

> header abc and blablabla
some_lines1
some_lines2
some_lines3
> header abc and blablabla
some_lines6
```

`:1;n;/^>/!b1` is a loop

`:1` is the label
`n` prints the current line and loads the next line into the pattern space
`/>/!` checks pattern space doesn't contain `>`  and if not executes next command
`b1` goes back to the start of the loop

Comment: @once added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^>/h;G;/^>.*abc/MP;d' file
```

This stores header lines in the hold space then appends the header to every line and only prints on a match.